# findOneandReplace keeps giving error: "Error: The replacement document must not contain atomic operators."?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently developing a Pokemon Team Builder app with a React frontend and an Express backend with MongoDB for the database.

As far as I can tell my TeamSchema has no such atomic operators? Here is my TeamSchema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const TeamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: 'String',
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  team: [
    {
      name: { type: String },
      types: [{ type: String }],
      sprite: { type: String },
    },
  ],
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  userId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const TeamModel = mongoose.model('Team', TeamSchema);

module.exports = TeamModel;
```

And the error gets thrown in this method when I attempt to call the findOneAndReplace method by finding a team that has a name and userId match.

```
const replaceTeam = async (req, res) => {
  const { teamName: name, filteredTeam: team } = req.body;
  const { username, _id: userId } = req.user;
  const newTeam = new Team({ name, team, username, userId });

  try {
    const replacedTeam = await Team.findOneAndReplace({ name, userId }, newTeam);
    console.log(replacedTeam);
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Team was successfully overwritten!' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred while updating the team.' });
  }
};
```

This has been a real headscratcher here and I am not sure what is going wrong here. I have only started using mongoose a couple of weeks ago, so I wonder if it's something fundamental I am misunderstanding here.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `console.log` on the data being passed into `newTeam` to ensure that the data is correct, and confirming that `newTeam` does contain a valid model?

Comment: Yes, it certainly looks valid to me, here's what `newTeam` outputs for me: https://pastebin.com/BQBj2q1T. That being said it does look like the Pokemon inside the Team object objects themselves are being given _id's even though I never explicitly set those. Is that where the atomic operator is coming from? And if so what can I do to circumvent this and be able to successfully replace the document?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is what it is referring to when it talks about atomic operators. Is `Team` in the `const newTeam = new Team` line the MongooseJS `TeamModel` being imported?

Comment: Yes at the top of the file: `const Team = require('../models/Team');`

Comment: `findOneAndReplace` is expecting a document object, not a model. Once you call `const newTeam = new Team`, newTeam is now a model and has already been created in the DB. Create `newTeam` as an object with the required fields rather than using `new Team` and see if that works.

Comment: Oh wow, you are totally right. Passing it in as a plain JavaScript object worked, looks like it was just my fundamental misunderstanding of how the `findOneAndReplace` method works, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mongoose function findOneAndReplace expects a document object passed in. See the below code.

```
details.findOneAndReplace(
  { location: "New York" },
  { name: "Sunny", age: 292, location: "Detroit" },
  function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  }
);
```

Change

```
const newTeam = new Team({ name, team, username, userId })
```

to

```
const newTeam = {name, team, username, userId}
```

Also as in the other poster's code, add the `new: true` option to the call as follows by changing

```
const replacedTeam = await Team.findOneAndReplace({ name, userId }, newTeam);
```

to

```
const replacedTeam = await Team.findOneAndReplace({ name, userId }, newTeam, { new: true });
```

otherwise the original document will be returned into `replacedTeam`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `findOneAndUpdate` and update all the fields with new data. You can do it like this:

```
const replaceTeam = async (req, res) => {
  const { teamName: name, filteredTeam: team } = req.body;
  const { username, _id: userId } = req.user;
  try {
    const replacedTeam = await Team.findOneAndUpdate({ name, userId }, { name, team, username, userId }, {new: true});
    console.log(replacedTeam);
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Team was successfully overwritten!' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred while updating the team.' });
  }
};
```